# Does left-cancellativity of an element imply that in a superstructure, it has a left inverse?

Tags: abstract-algebra, magma

Let $X$ denote a magma and suppose $x \in X$. Then clearly, if there exists a magma $Y$ and an injective homomorphism $f : X \rightarrow Y$ such that $f(x)$ has a left-inverse, then it follows that $x$ is left-cancellative.

Does the converse hold?

Meaning, is it true that if $x \in X$ is left-cancellative, then there exists a magma $Y$ and an injective homomorphism $f : X \rightarrow Y$ such that $f(x)$ has a left-inverse?

My definitions are as follows.

"$x$ is left-cancellative" =

$$\forall a,b : x*a = x*b \rightarrow a=b$$

"$x$ has a left-inverse" =

$$\exists y \forall a : y*(x*a)=a.$$

Answer (score 2):

You can simply pick $Y = X \cup \{x^{-1}\}$ and find a way to extend $*$ to $Y$ :

Define $x^{-1} * (x*a) = a$ forall $a \in X$ (this is possible since $x \mapsto x * a$ is injective).
For $x * x^{-1}$, pick any result in $Y \setminus \{ x * a, a \in X\}$, so you can define next $x^{-1} * (x * x^{-1}) = x^{-1}$. For the remaining operations involving $x^{-1}$, you don't have any constraint so anything you pick works.

Comment: Okay, I get the first point, namely that we're allowed to stipulate that $x^{-1} * (x * a) = a,$ by injectivity. For the second point, I think we have a problem, which is that $Y \setminus \{x * a, a \in X\}$ might be empty.

Comment: no, because it always contain at least $x^{-1}$. It can contain other things if $X$ is infinite and left-composition by $x$ is not surjective.